# Writing put method for hashmap

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, data-structures, hashmap

I am currently writing a put method for a hashmap implementation I have. This is what I have so far:

```
@Override
    public boolean put(K key, V value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // can also use key.hashCode() assuming key is not null
        for(int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i += 1) {
            buckets[i] = new ArrayList<HashMapEntry<K, V>>();
        }
        if(key == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ILLEGAL_ARG_NULL_KEY);
        }
        int keyHash = key.hashCode();
        int index = Math.abs(keyHash % capacity);
        if(buckets[index].equals(key)) {
            return(false);
        } else {
            buckets[index].add(new HashMapEntry<K, V>(key, value));
            size += 1;
            if(capacity / size >= loadFactor) {
                expandCapacity();
            }
            return(true);
        }
    }
```

The put method should do as follows:

```
/**
     * Replaces the value that maps to the key if it is present
     * @param key The key whose mapped value is being replaced
     * @param newValue The value to replace the existing value with
     * @return true if the key was in this DefaultMap
     * @throws IllegalArgument exception if the key is null
     */
```

When testing, my method so far does none of this except correctly throwing the IllegalArgumentException if the key being passed thru is null. I am stuck on how to do the rest part of this method, so any help with justification is appreciated!

Java code I am working with:
[MyHashMap.java](https://github.com/ucsd-cse12-f22/cse12-pa6-HashMap/blob/master/pa6-starter/src/MyHashMap.java)
[DefaultMap.java](https://github.com/ucsd-cse12-f22/cse12-pa6-HashMap/blob/master/pa6-starter/src/DefaultMap.java)
[MyHashMapTest.java](https://github.com/ucsd-cse12-f22/cse12-pa6-HashMap/blob/master/pa6-starter/src/MyHashMapTest.java)

Comment: `put` adds an entry to a hash map.  It seems the first thing you do when adding an entry is to replace all existing buckets, i.e., throwing away everything already in the map.

Comment: Do not share external code source. Paste here the minimal code needed to test your stuff, that's how it works here :)

Comment: `buckets[i] = new ArrayList<HashMapEntry<K, V>>()` you're resetting each bucket every time you call put

Answer (score 1):

At the very beginning of your method, you're cleaning out all the previous data from the `buckets` array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i += 1) {
    buckets[i] = new ArrayList<HashMapEntry<K, V>>();
}
```

Which is wrong, `put()` should not affect existing data.

The following condition is always `false`, `HashMapEntry` can't be equal to a Key, hence it's pointless.

```
if (buckets[index].equals(key))
```

According to your requirements:

> Replaces the value that maps to the **key if it is present**
>
> ...
>
> @return `true` if the key was in this DefaultMap

So you need to access the target bucket, and iterate over its list to find out if the given *Key* exists. If the Key was found, then you need to replace the *Value* associated with it with the given *Value* and return `true`. Otherwise, return `false`